# I want to know what these line of code means , much appreciable if I get to know in detail

Tags: javascript, string, split

```js
let text = "Hello";

const myArr = text.split("");

text = "";

for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  text += myArr[i] + "<br>"
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<span id="demo" />
```

Comment: the same as `text = Array.from(text).join('<br>') + '<br>'`  ;-)

Comment: You can visualize each line here. Click on `Next` button:  https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=let%20text%20%3D%20%22Hello%22%3B%0A%0Aconst%20myArr%20%3D%20text.split%28%22%22%29%3B%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%0Afor%20%28let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20myArr.length%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20text%20%2B%3D%20myArr%5Bi%5D%20%2B%20%22%3Cbr%3E%22%0A%7D&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Answer (score 0):

Don't hesistate to use console.log + some googling to understand what the script does:

```
// Assign Hello string to text variable
let text = "Hello";
console.log(text);

// Split text ("Hello") with token "", that's to say split into an array of character (['H','e','l','l','o'])
const myArr = text.split("");
console.log(myArr);

// Set text to an empty string
text = "";
console.log(text)

// Loop on myArr (['H','e','l','l','o']) and concat its element separated by "<br>"
for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  text += myArr[i] + "<br>"
  console.log(`what text looks like after iteration ${i}: ${text}`)
}
console.log(text)

// Set the inner html of element in the dom with id "demo" to text
// It should display H, e, l, l, o with line breaks
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```